# Delete blank line before a pattern. What's wrong? Currently using Perl but open to sed/AWK

Tags: regex, bash, perl, newline

In a long document, I want to selectively delete the particular newlines that precede the exact string `\begin{enumerate*}`, ideally with a one-liner in bash or zsh.

That is, I want to convert **test.tex**:

```
Text in paragraphs.

More text

\begin{enumerate*} \item thing
```

to

```
Text in paragraphs.

More text \begin{enumerate*} \item thing
```

with a one-liner like

```
cat test.tex | perl -p -e 's/\n(?=(\\begin\{enumerate\*\}))/ /'
```

or

```
cat test.tex | perl -p -e 's/\n\\begin\{enumerate\*\}/\\begin{enumerate*}/'
```

but I must be missing something because it doesn't make any change.

I also clearly don't need a regular expression here. If there's a way to do this with exact string matching instead of regex, I'd rather use that way. For instance, in R I could do this with `sub("\n\\begin{enumerate*}", "\\begin{enumerate*}", fixed = TRUE)`.

Comment: You can use the `\Q ... \E` escape here to make escaping meta characters simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-0` (digit zero) switch with Perl to specify the line separator. Traditionally `-0777` is used to read the entire file

You also need to be careful about regex metacharacters in your search string. Characters like `*`, `{`, `}` and `\` mean something special within a regex pattern, and you should escape them — usually with a `\Q` ... `\E` construct

Taking these points into account, this should work for you

```
perl -0777 -pe' s/\n+(?=\Q\begin{enumerate*}\E)/ / ' myfile
```

Answer (score 1):

`perl -p` processes a file *string by string*, so you can't expect this regex to match.

I would recommend something like

```
perl -e '$text = join "", <>; $text =~ s/your_regex_here//; print $text' test.txt
```

Mind that it loads the whole file to memory.

Also, if you want to modify file immediately, you can't just say `> test.txt`, see [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/135507/linux-how-to-use-a-file-as-input-and-output-at-the-same-time/).

Comment: That's what I had thought originally, but I was under the impression that it somehow worked on the entire file from another stackoverflow answer. The file isn't too large to fit in memory, but maybe it would be better to use AWK in two passes or something like that

Comment: You can also add `BEGIN { undef $/ }` which means "read the whole file as a string".

Comment: In that case you can use `-i` to modify file "in place".

Comment: @VadimPushtaev Or since it is a one-liner, use the command line switch `-0777` for "slurp mode".

Comment: @VadimPushtaev: That is traditionally written as `perl -0777` for one-line Perl programs

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with sed (number 25 on [this page](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/06/sed-25-examples-to-delete-line-or.html)) that doesn't read the entire file into memory:

```
sed -i bak -n '/^\\begin{enumerate\*}/{x;d;};1h;1!{x;p;};${x;p;}' test.tex
```

The downside is that this doesn't actually join the two lines; instead it produces

```
Text in paragraphs.

More text
\begin{enumerate*} \item thing
```

which is good enough for what I need (latex treats single newlines the same as regular spaces)